# How do i save the root elements width and height in px rather than in mm?

Tags: inkscape

I have typed the following `G` in my inkscape:

[image: G alphabet]

Now when i save this SVG i get the following output:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-46.428571"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       x="2.8571408"
       y="189.50507"
       id="text4136"
       sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan4138"
         x="2.8571408"
         y="189.50507"
         style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:180px;font-family:edges;-inkscape-font-specification:edges">G</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see the root element has the following two attributes:

```
width="210mm" height="297mm"
```

Now the width and height here are saved in `mm`. What i would really like is if the width and height both can be saved in `px`. How do i do this in inkscape ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open `File > Document Properties` or click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
- Select `px` in the dropdown menu next to the document size.
- The current document size will be converted to the same size in px.

[image]